# How to display background in status bar?

Tags: java, android

I want my app to look like this :

[image]

What I have:
[image]

Any help would be deeply appreciated!

Comment: https://github.com/rohitksingh/Notely/commit/0f3fc929dac28911cc0f3c494155d15a4c79a45c  check this out see if it helps you. give a thumps up if it is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change color primary and color primary dark in style.xml where your app theme color code was written

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply man but I have applied a PNG image as the background  and it has a gradient effect in it so it's not a clean look.

Answer (score 1):

change from colorPrimaryDark to colorPrimary to all the item in style.xml file.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```